# Two counts in one query with opposing where criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I have two separate queries that work fine by themselves but I need them to work in one query. I can combine the results easily enough in excel but this is to be part of a larger query.

The two separate queries are:

```
SELECT 
    SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, 
    COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM 
    SiteProductVariation 
INNER JOIN 
    SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE 
    (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) 
    AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0)
GROUP BY 
    SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

and

```
SELECT 
    SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, 
    COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM 
    SiteProductVariation 
INNER JOIN 
    SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE 
    (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) 
    AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 1)
GROUP BY 
    SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

For this `ProductVariationID` there are 11 Siteproductids, 7 with Productdisplay=1 and 4 with ProductDisplay=0, and these queries do return that information fine.

But I tried to combine them into:

```
SELECT 
    SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, 
    COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1, 
    COUNT(SiteProduct_1.SiteProductID) AS Expr2
FROM 
    SiteProductVariation 
INNER JOIN 
    SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID 
INNER JOIN 
    SiteProduct AS SiteProduct_1 ON SiteProduct_1.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE 
    (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) 
    AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0) 
    AND (SiteProduct_1.ProductDisplay = 1)
GROUP BY 
    SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

and get no results. I think it is because of using group by when I looked this problem up.

Any help is appreciate even if to say I can't do this. There is a chance a siteproductid may have 0 results with ProductDisplay equalling 1 or 0 so that may need to be taken into account. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding to the answers already given: By using two inner joins you only get SiteProductVariations that have both a SiteProduct record with ProductDisplay = 0 and one with ProductDisplay = 1. You *could* use left outer joins instead, move the ProductDisplay criteria to the ON clauses and count distinct IDs, but it's much better to query the table just once as shown by Cetin Basoz (only the explanation given there is not accurate).

Comment: "Explanation given there is not accurate" ??? You think an SQL as simple as this requires any explanation at all ?

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: Sorry, no offense meant :-) "The value cannot be both 0 and 1 at the same time" is wrong. It could well be that two SiteProduct records exist for one SiteProductVariation, one with ProductDisplay 0 and one with 1. So you are not really explaining what is wrong with the OP's query. But your solution is good.

Comment: Oh you are right, I missed that he aliased them differently as  SiteProduct and SiteProduct_1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT     SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0 THEN  SiteProduct.SiteProductID END) AS Expr1
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 1 THEN  SiteProduct.SiteProductID END) AS Expr2
FROM SiteProductVariation 
INNER JOIN SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID 
WHERE (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) 
  AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0 
       OR 
      SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 1)
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

Comment: You solution is nice except that it is referring to non existant SiteProduct_1 alias. I was trapped with the same misconception too :) It would be just SIteProduct.ProductDisplay

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I removed  AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0 OR SiteProduct_1.ProductDisplay = 1), as 0 and 1 are the only 2 states it can be in. I applied it to a larger query that this was part of, and after adding DISTINCT before CASE due to the way its joined, it too worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT     SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, 
SUM(CASE WHEN SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expr1,
SUM(CASE WHEN SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expr2
FROM         SiteProductVariation INNER JOIN
                      SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE     (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay IN (0,1))
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the first version to use `IN`.  Also, simplify the query using table aliases:

```
SELECT spv.ProductVariationID, COUNT(sp.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM SiteProductVariation spv INNER JOIN
     SiteProduct sp
     ON sp.SiteProductID = spv.SiteProductID
WHERE (spv.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND
      (sp.ProductDisplay IN (0, 1))
GROUP BY spv.ProductVariationID;
```

As a note:  Your version would work with `OR` between the two conditions on `ProductDisplay` rather than `AND`.

If you want the results with the `ProductDisplay` values separated, then include that in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT spv.ProductVariationID, sp.ProductDisplay,
       COUNT(sp.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM SiteProductVariation spv INNER JOIN
     SiteProduct sp
     ON sp.SiteProductID = spv.SiteProductID
WHERE (spv.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND
      (sp.ProductDisplay IN (0, 1))
GROUP BY spv.ProductVariationID, sp.ProductDisplay;
```

Comment: This would return the total count in either SiteProduct.ProductDisplay is 0 or 1. I think he wants to have the counts for 0 and 1 doing the SQLs separate initially.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `AND` clause in your query which is the root cause. Use `OR` instead because you want either of the condition to satisfy and not simultaneously. The statement should be `((SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0) OR (SiteProduct_1.ProductDisplay = 1))` because the value can be `0 or 1` and `not 0 and 1` at the same time.

So the query becomes:

```
SELECT     SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1, COUNT(SiteProduct_1.SiteProductID) AS Expr2
FROM         SiteProductVariation INNER JOIN
                      SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID INNER JOIN
                      SiteProduct AS SiteProduct_1 ON SiteProduct_1.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE     (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND ((SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0) OR (SiteProduct_1.ProductDisplay = 1))
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the UNION clause.

```
SELECT SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, 
COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM  SiteProductVariation 
INNER JOIN SiteProduct 
ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) 
AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0)
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
UNION
SELECT SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM SiteProductVariation INNER JOIN
SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE     (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 1)
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include results from both queries by using `UNION`.

If you want to return only distinct (ie non-duplicated) rows, then just use `UNION` by itself.  If you want all rows from both queries then use `UNION ALL` instead.

```
SELECT     SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1
FROM         SiteProductVariation INNER JOIN
                      SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE     (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 1)
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
UNION --Note you could use UNION ALL here if you want all rows returning
SELECT     SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID, COUNT(SiteProduct.SiteProductID) AS Expr1, COUNT(SiteProduct_1.SiteProductID) AS Expr2
FROM         SiteProductVariation INNER JOIN
                      SiteProduct ON SiteProduct.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID INNER JOIN
                      SiteProduct AS SiteProduct_1 ON SiteProduct_1.SiteProductID = SiteProductVariation.SiteProductID
WHERE     (SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID = 159868) AND (SiteProduct.ProductDisplay = 0) AND (SiteProduct_1.ProductDisplay = 1)
GROUP BY SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID
```

Comment: Union is not a solution IMHO. Instead of a UNION adding SiteProduct_1.ProductDisplay to the SQL itself would be a simpler solution if the poster wanted to get 2 rows per SiteProductVariation.ProductVariationID,